# How to install let's encrypt ssl in Goautodial 4 CentOS 7?

Tags: server, ssl-certificate, centos7, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am having trouble in Goautodial 4 server that i installed recently. Bcz the index.php page it shows that ssl certificate is ok and installed, but when i login as user the agent.php page is unsecure. How can I manage that all the pages shows with https?
I would really appreciate some help.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

So far this is what i have done to install the let's encrypt ssl.

1- I have installed the EPEL repository as it is not available by default :

`sudo yum install -y epel-release mod_ssl`

2- Than I created virtual host for port 80

Created a file with server.domain.com.conf :

`nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/server.domain.com.conf`

and inserted inside this code :

`<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.server.domain.com
  ServerAlias server.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
</VirtualHost>`

`systemctl restart httpd`

3- Installed the certbot client from the EPEL repository :

`sudo yum install python-certbot-apache`

4- Generated the certificate for the server.domain.com :

`sudo certbot --apache -d server.domain.com`

5- Entered yes for all the questions during installation and redirect all to https.

6- I set up a crontab for the renewal process :

`sudo crontab -e`

`0 0 * * 1 / usr / bin / certbot renew >> /var/log/sslrenew.log`

That's all.